# how to delay a click event until a $http call is finished and page content is ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I created a modal which is fetching its content using a `$http` call. The amount of data coming from this `$http` call varies account by account. So, sometimes the modal is not ready yet and if user clicks the button to open the modal it will show nothing for a while.

I want to delay the click event until the content of the modal is ready. I mean, I want the modal to be opened whenever it is completely rendered. I tried `$timeout` service to do that but it is not good since some accounts need more time and some of them need less:

```
$('#modalLink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $timeout(function() {
            $("#myModal").modal({
            persist: true,
            height: 'auto',
            maxWidth: 900,
            onClose: function (dialog) {
                $.modal.close();
             }
        });
        }, 500);
    });
```

So how can I set the click event to delay until my scope object `($scope.myArray)` is defined?

Comment: What moment the `http` is called? Because..angular http returns a promise, and you can check if promisse gone done to open the modal.

Comment: put the modal code in the callback for your ajax function and the modal wont open until it's ready... simple. if you want something to happen before something else, put it higher up in the code.. that said, best practice for ux is to show the user something immediately after they click a button, else they're likely to press it several times. i would recommend opening the modal and showing a spinner until the content is loaded.

Comment: I would advise against not showing the modal until the data is there for UX reasons. The user will think the page is unresponsive. Just show a spinner within the modal body until the data is ready.

Comment: where do you make `$http call`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy answer is to show a spinner in your modal, when data is loading. After it is loaded, you hide the spinner and show the data. I would prefer to do it that way.

However, if you do not want to show spinner, you can start loading your data with $http and put opening of your modal in .then() statement of Promise that $http.get, $http.post, etc provides.

Like

```
$('#modalLink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $http.get(blablabla).then(fucntion(){
        //open your modal here
    };
});
```

Please read more about promises here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

P.s. I would also recommend you using Services approach to get data from server.

**Update**

Also, please do not forget to catch errors with .catch() method.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I finally ended up with this which was my first thought.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is, set some kind of flag when your `$http` has resolved:

```
$http.get('/url')
    .then(function(res) {
        $scope.flag = true;
    });
```

Now, set an `ng-show` on the modal or the modal trigger button, to be true for `$scope.flag`

Or even better, set a loading GIF on the Modal, that has shows itself as long as `flag` is false. Once your promise resolves, hide this loading icon, and show your modal content.

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="overlay" ng-show="!flag"></div>
    <div class="modal-content" ng-show="flag"></div>
</div>
```

You can also disable the button in a similar function

Comment: With this way, the user can show some loading gif inside `$('#modalLink').click`, but, the function will be in a loop verifying if flag is true. I isn't the more elegant way.

Comment: It's just a general direction for OP to come to an elegant solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the button is

```
<button ng-disabled="isDisabled">Button</button>
```

And in controller:

```
$scope.isDisabled = true;

$http.get('someUrl')
     .then(function(result){
     $scope.isDisabled = false;
})
```

This will ensure the button is disabled on page load but enabled after function call.

Answer (score 0):

try [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)  and get data in modal's resolve 
the modal resolve works same like router resolve

Example:

`$scope.openModal = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'stackedModal.html', // you can use template option instead templateUrl
      size: 'sm',
      resolve: {
          items: function () {
              return //do something that you want.
          }
      }
      controller: function($scope, items) {
          //your data is in items injector. 
      }
});`